# how to apply json.loads to each row in pandas df

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have pandas df with column `metadata`. This column contains nested dictionaries. I want to get rid of single quotes around the values in each row. `json.loads(data)` worked fine with just one value that I passed.

Example below:

```
data = '{"dek": "<p>Don\'t forget to buy a card</p>", "links": {"edit": {"dev": "...}}}'
data_json = json.loads(data)
data
```

Output: 
`{"dek": "<p>Don\'t forget to buy a card</p>", "links": {"edit": {"dev": "...}}}`

However when I try to implement this to every row in `metadata` column, it give me an error. Here is the code:

```
for index, row in sample_df.iterrows():
    sample_df['metadata'] = json.loads(sample_df["metadata"])
```

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series`

Example of the dataset:

```
id    metadata                                         title 
123  {"dek": "<p>Student loan debt is crippling a g... channel
124  {"dek": "<p>Student loan debt is crippling a...   fashion
```

Answer (score 8):

Try with this code:

```
sample_df['metadata'] = sample_df['metadata'].apply(json.loads)
```

The Panda's apply function, pass the function on every value of the series. It's very useful because you can skip the iteration on every row.
If you want more information about this function and the parameters that you can change, refer to the official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: Hmmm it gives me the exact same error: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict`

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but you use the code outside the for loop? Can you share a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: Outside of the for loop, correct. And I edited my question providing an example of the dataset. The type of `metadata` column is Series

Comment: In my environment works correctly. You can try with json.dumps instead of json.loads. If it doesn't work, can you send me the version of pandas and json?

Comment: I ran the following: `sample_df['metadata'] = sample_df['metadata'].apply(json.loads)`  this time it didn't error out but the output of a single value from that row still has the quotations around the dicts. I ran this command: `val = sample_df['metadata'].values[0]`

Comment: json.dumps gave me back additional quotations marks, so that didn't work either :/

Comment: Ok, I understand. If you see the dataframe, you can't see the quotation marks around the dictionary, but the value stored in the metadata column, after the json.loads, is a string type; so if you retrieve a single value, the output is a string. If you can explain me better what is your goal, I can try to help you better.

Comment: I simply want to extract the quotes around the nested dictionary so then I can iterate through each row and get key, value pair. At the meantime when I try to iterate through the rows it gives me the error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'` so I am trying to get rid of the quotes so it becomes dictionaries format. Maybe there is a better solution for what I am trying to achieve, only json.load worked on a sample and I can't find a way to iterate this method through each row... Hope that helps :)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. You can try something like this:

`for items in df['metadata3']:
    for key, value in items.items():
        print(key)`

Obviously with the correct indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I read the question wrong. You want to convert the string into a python dict. Here is a complete, working example.

```py
from io import StringIO
import json
import pandas as pd

# Read data
s = StringIO("""id,metadata,title 
123,{"dek": "<p>Student loan</p>"},channel
124,{"dek": "<p>Student loan</p>"},fashion""")
df = pd.read_csv(s)

df.loc[:, "metadata"] = df.loc[:, "metadata"].apply(json.loads)
df.head()

# id    metadata    title
# 0 123 {'dek': '<p>Student loan</p>'}  channel
# 1 124 {'dek': '<p>Student loan</p>'}  fashion
```

In addition to [@Simone Coslovich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174642/5666087), you can use [DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: I did try that as well. `sample_df['metadata'] = sample_df['metadata'].to_json But it gave me an error. `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid` Which is weird because this column Is Series...

Comment: Ran the following: `df.loc[:, "metadata"] = df.loc[:, "metadata"].apply(json.loads)` and got the same error back, which is `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict`

Comment: That indicates `df["metadata"]` is already a `dict`... so problem solved?

Comment: Solved with the following code: `sample_df["new_column"] = sample_df.metadata.apply(json.loads)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
sample_df["new_column"] = sample_df.metadata.apply(json.loads)
```

The output is: `{"dek": "<p>Don\'t forget to buy a card</p>", "links": {"edit": {"dev": "...}}}`

Comment: The other two answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174691/5666087 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174642/5666087) already show this...

Comment: @jakub These are the answers for the same question (that I myself have posted) and none of them worked. I posted the answer that worked specifically for my issue.